# What would be the more practical uses for a Django application w/out a database?

Tags: python, django

I recently got into Django out of curiosity after developing for quite a while w/ Ruby on Rails and Node.js, and found that it's splendid for working w/ databases. Django is primarily known for working with databases and every tutorial I've ever found on it has included databases. Django supports not requiring databases however, and, just out of curiosity since I'm still rather inexperienced w/ Django, what would be some practical uses w/ Django w/out requiring databases?

Comment: Please just type out the word `with`. Just Find and Replace if you have to.

Comment: `With` which area are you referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend using Django if you are not interested in using a database.  Having written that disclaimer, if you insist on still using it, you can just scan over the documentation and identify what is still available to you if you do not have a database:

You can use Django's security features to help protect against clickjacking, cross site request forgeries, etc.

You can take advantage of Django's support for internationalization if you want to support multiple languages on your website.

You can have Django handle validation of any forms you have on your website.

...basically you can create a static website that takes advantage of the rapid prototyping enabled by a framework built using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of many if I'm honest. If you are writing a web application that doesn't need to store to retrieve things from some sort of storage then using a whole Django project is probably total overkill.

A blog wouldn't really require a database if you only had a single user who was willing to add posts by adding files manually, but something like [Jekell](http://jekyllrb.com/) would be better for that.

You could create a web app that would interact with the server it's on. For example, you could create a web page that called a unix command when you hit a create webpage. You would be able to use to this create some sort of dashboard for your server or maybe provide a cleaner user interface for things that you could do with ssh. However, Django might be overkill for this, something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) might work better as you would have a lot less overhead.